# Could a person do the shinigami deal without losing half his lifespan?

Tags: death-note

Quick question, if you trade half of your life for shinigami eyes and it happens to save your life, would you lose only half of the time you would have lived, or would you somehow lose half of the life that you would actually live since the eyes saved your life?

Bad example:

1. 1 and 2 in a room
2. 2 has 1's name and is about to write his name down in his Death Note
3. 1 doesnt have 2's name and can't write his down in his Death Note
4. 1 would only have about 30 seconds to live
5. 1 Trades half of his life for Shinigami eyes
6. 1 Writes 2's name down without him knowing and before he writes 1's name down.

Would 1 have 30(-15) seconds to live, or x(÷2)? And there's always the possibility of having his full life and only losing 15 seconds, x(-15).

Comment: I think your question would have been better if 2 wouldn't have had a DN. Like when Misa was about to be killed by her stalker. I think if at that point she would have had the DN, she could have indeed increased her lifespan and would only lose half of the original remaining lifespan, because at the time of the trade, it wasn't sure yet, whether she would write his name in time or would still end up dying

Comment: I am beginning to love those DN rules lawyering.

Comment: Asking for a friend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your theory:

1. Death by Death Note doesn't count in the user's lifespan. Even if you have 80 more years to live, if I write your name down now you die 30 seconds later.
2. A Death Note will not work on someone with 12 minutes or less left to live. According to How to Use: XXIX.

So no, the user would lose half of his original lifespan. The only way to extend a lifespan is to get a Shinigami to die for you.

Comment: What if 2 wouldn't have had a DN? Basically what would happen if Misa had a Death Note at the time she was about to be stabbed and asked for the Shinigami eyes at the particular point? Then i think her lifespan would indeed increase as OP points out.

Comment: Yes, that's actually sounds plausible.

Comment: @Peter Raeves i don't understand your comment.

Comment: @user6399 The situation would be different. In your situation you would pay half of your remaining life to survive the other half of that life. If the person is about to kill you with lets say a gun, then your lifespan would be really short and you would actually extend your life by using the Death God.

Comment: ah so if a person wants to kill me with a gun, and i would trade the half of my remaining lifespan to see his name and then i would kill him. would i then prolong my life?

Answer (score 1):

Original lifespan has to do with a humans lifespan without any intervening of a deathnote or death god!

So if someone makes the deal for their eyes they lose half of their remaining lifespan. 
(Getting the eyes to kill someone who is about to write your name down on a deathnote is a situation not counted in your "original lifespan"...

Comment: but your lifespan would have been shortened because to person would kill you. But if you could get the shinigami eyes, you could kill him. So i think this could work

Answer (score 0):

If someone wrote their own name in the death note and then did the eye deal the shinigami will not be able to cut his lifespan as he has already written his name in one death note before the shinigami

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? I don't remember them ever saying this. If you deduced it from the rules, can you explain which rules and how it works?